# Optimizing a counter that loops through documents to check how many words from the document appear in a list

Tags: python

I am using a lexicon of positive and negative words, and I want to count how many positive and negative words appear in each document from a large corpus. The corpus has almost 2 million documents, so the code I'm running is taking too long to count all these occurrences.

I have tried using numpy, but get a memory error when trying to convert the list of documents into an array.

This is the code I am currently running to count just the positive words in each document.

```py
reviews_pos_wc = []

for review in reviews_upper:
    pos_words = 0
    for word in review:
        if word in pos_word_list:
            pos_words += 1
    reviews_pos_wc.append(pos_words)
```

After running this for half an hour, it only gets through 300k documents.

I have done a search for similar questions on this website. I found someone else doing a similar thing, but not nearly on the same scale as they only used one document. The answer suggested using the Counter class, but I thought this would just add more overhead.

Comment: Have you considered using an nlp library like Spacy, gensim or nltk?

Comment: Reading each word in 2 million documents is guaranteed to take a lot of time. Counter will help reduce the amount of code you write, but probably won't do a lot to improve the speed.

Comment: @Dan Yes but is there a way to incorporate my lexicons? I am specifically trying to test those.

Comment: I have found a way to convert my uppercase list into a numpy array by directly converting from pandas which has a vectorized operation.

Comment: Asking for library references is specifically off-topic for SO.  That's an individual research topic.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your central problem is that you don't have the hardware needed to do the job you want in the time you want.  For instance, your RAM appears insufficient to hold the names of 2M documents in both list and array form.

I do see a couple of possibilities.  Note that "vectorization" is not a magic solution to large problems; it's merely a convenient representation that allows certain optimizations to occur among repeated operations.

Regularize your file names, so that you can represent their names in fewer bytes.  Iterate through a descriptive expression, rather than the full file names.  This could give you freedom to vectorize something later.

Your variable implies that your lexicon is a list.  This has inherently linear access.  Change this to a data structure amenable to faster search, such as a set (hash function) or some appropriate search tree.  Even a sorted list with an interpolation search would speed up your work.

Do consider using popular modules (such as `Collections`); let the module developers optimize the common operations on your behalf.  Write a prototype and time its performance: given the simplicity of your processing, the coding shouldn't take long.

Does that give you some ideas for experimentation?  I'm hopeful that my first paragraph proves to be unrealistically pessimistic (i.e. that something does provide a solution, especially the lexicon set).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn't realize that using the ```in``` keyword on lists is less efficient than a hashed data structure. I am currently trying to use scikit-learn's CountVectorizer with a custom vocabulary, but if that does not work I'll try converting the list to a set.

Comment: You still use `in` with a set.  The difference is in the available implementation for `in`.  For a set, it's an **O(1)** hash function already defined on the data type.  For a list, it's a sequential search.  You can also define your own in a new class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After implementing the set and preprocessing the documents, the code runs in about 30 seconds now. The main problem before besides the list being slower was that I was looping through the characters in the string rather than the words.

Comment: Ah, ha!  We could have caught that sooner if you'd given an MCVE instead of a snippet.  Most important, we got your main problems handled.